# How to calculate % of area for each slope class in a tiff file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a slope tiff layer. The pixel type is floating points. I categorized them in 3 classes based on the values. Now I need to know the number of cells in each class but this layer does not have a attribute table.

How can I calculate the % of the study area in the 3 classes?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 I was trying to write a con statement using raster calculator but it has not worked yet.

Comment: Have you tried the Tabulate Area tool? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [Reclassify tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) in the Reclass toolset of Spatial Analyst. This is more commonly used to remap categorical raster values on a one-to-one basis, e.g. change all cells with a value `x` to a new value `y`. But Reclassify can also be used to map ranges of values in interval rasters, as shown here:

[image: Reclassify range]

The [Reclass by Range](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclass-by-ranges-of-values.htm) help page has additional information that may be useful.

If you have an exceptionally large number of ranges, you can also use the related [Reclass by Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclass-by-table.htm) and [Reclass by ASCII](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclass-by-ascii-file.htm) to input the mapping instead of using the table in the tool window.